# jqGrid Filter toolbar displays records that does not have search key

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have following jqGrid with filter toolbar. Filtering is working. But when I type “N” in the first name search column, it is listing records that does not have “N” in it. This is shown in the screenshot below. How can we fix this?

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/rqab1veh/)

[image]

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myData = [

                { "id": "35", "firstname": null, "codeval": "G", "note": "xx7866", "amount": "23" },
                { "id": "73", "firstname": null, "codeval": "W", "note": "dd1047", "amount": "34" },
                { "id": "75", "firstname": "LORA", "codeval": "H", "note": "rr7323", "amount": "56" },
                { "id": "95", "firstname": "EST", "codeval": "M", "note": "gg574", "amount": "55" }
                ],

                myGrid = $("#list");

            myGrid.jqGrid({
                datatype:'local',
                data: myData,
                colNames: ['ID', 'FirstName', 'Code', 'Amount', 'Note'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id',width:70,align:'center',sorttype: 'int'},
                    {name:'firstname',index:'firstname',width:80, align:'center'},
                    { name: 'codeval', index: 'codeval', width: 70 },
                    {name:'amount',index:'amount',width:100, formatter:'number', align:'right'},
                    {name:'note',index:'note',width:100,sortable:false}
                ],
                rowNum:10,
                pager: '#pager',
                gridview:true,
                ignoreCase:true,
                rownumbers:true,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                height: '100%'
            });
            myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });

        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described a bug in jqGrid 4.6.

[The line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L339)

```
phrase.push("String("+s+")");
```

of jqGrid code should be fixed, for example, to the following

```
phrase.push("String(" + s + " || '')");
```

The main problem: you use **dead version of jqGrid: 4.6, which is about 3 years old**. There are exist now two main forks of jqGrid: commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) and alternative fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop.

If you would use the current release of free jqGrid (the version 4.13.6), then I could suggest you to use `jsonmap` as the workaround

```
{ name: 'firstname', width: 80, align: 'center',
    jsonmap: function (item) {
        return item.firstname != null ? item.firstname : "";
     } }
```

See the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/rqab1veh/1/

Of cause, I fixed the bug in the latest code of free jqGrid (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/5d46f2241dcec1745966253c2276eecac6042e81)). You can download the fixed cde from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). You can verify on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/rqab1veh/3/, that your code has no problem in case of usage the latest code of free jqGrid from GitHub.

I don't see any workaround of the problem, which you reported, in jqGrid 4.6. I can suggest you either to upgrade to the latest code of free jqGrid or to make your custom build of jqGrid 4.6 with the bug fix, which I described before.